# Download App updates seperately for Mac and iPad?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, itunes-store

If I download iPad App updates via iTunes on a Mac, shouldn't they automatically sync when I connect the iPad to the Mac?

I plugged an iPad 3 (iOS 6.1.3) into a Mac (OS X 10.6.8) running iTunes (11.0.2).

The iPad was waiting for 8 App updates, as was the Mac.  I downloaded, via iTunes, all the updates on the Mac, and then ran a sync.  The iPad was still waiting for the 8 updates.

Music and photos seem to sync OK.

Is this the normal behaviour?  Seems strange to have to download everything twice...

Comment: Looks like the answer is, in iTunes:

File > Devices > Transfer Purchases from ""

You can also access this function via the gear icon in the sidebar (assuming you have this visible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is as follows:

- Download updates on the iPad
- Connect iPad to computer running iTunes
- In iTunes, select `File > Devices > Transfer Purchases from "<iPad name>"`

This causes the update that you've already downloaded on your iPad to be transferred to your computer, and iTunes shouldn't try and download it again.